# Can't shut down in GNOME-shell 3.8

Tags: gnome, 13.04, shutdown

For the past month or so I've been unable to shut down or reboot my PC from GNOME-shell. I am running 3.8 from the staging PPA which is otherwise working beautifully. When I attempt to shut down or reboot it gets as far as stripping the themes from applications and then goes no further. In order to shut down I have to open a terminal emulator and `sudo shutdown -h now`.

Running `gnome-session-quit --power-off` does not yield any terminal output.

Comment: Try running `gnome-session-logout` in a terminal, and see what the output is. I'm not sure if that's the right command, but it'll autocomplete with `gnome-session-<tab>[-<tab>]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install systemd-shim
```

and then restart

Answer (score 3):

Until someone comes up with a proper fix, you could create an icon on your Desktop which would run your command without having to open terminal first.

## Step 1

Using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> type

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

This will launch the old GUI Dialog and create a launcher on your Desktop:

[image]

## Step 2

fill in the details with your command line of `sudo shutdown -h now` and you are ready to  shut down with a single(or double) click of your mouse.

Hope this helps